# backbone pagination current page bug

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

im trying to get a pagination in backbone/underscore to work properly. It works fine on init and on next/prev navigation.

But when i try to set the current page on run time it flips out and renders the wrong page numbers. It only gets wrong if i set the current page to something more than 8. Everyting under 8 works fine. Here is my template, it renders only 10 page numbers at a time, credits to 
Rida BENHAMMANE!

Template:

```
        <script type="text/template" id="pagination_template">
        <section class="pagination">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="paging prev">&#9668;</div>
                </li>
                <% 
                    var renderPages;
                    for (var i = 0; i <= pages-1; i++) {
                        renderPages = false;
                        if (pages < 10) {
                            renderPages = true;
                        } else {
                            if (current <= 5) {
                                if (i < 10) {
                                    renderPages = true;
                                }
                            } else if (current <= pages - 5) {
                                if ((current - 5) < i && (current + 5) > i) {
                                    renderPages = true;
                                }
                            } else {
                                if ((pages - 9) < i) {
                                    renderPages = true;
                                }
                            }
                        };

                        if(renderPages) { %>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#" data-offset="<%= i*9 %>" data-page="<%= i %>">
                                    <%= i+1 %>
                                </a>
                            </li> 
                        <% }
                    } 
                %>
                <li>
                    <div class="paging next">&#9658;</div>
                </li>
            </ul>    <br><br>
               total pages <%= pages %>           
        </section>
    </script>
```

And here is the function the changes the current page and renders the navigaton.
Current pages is set to a data-attribute of the clicked element.

```
        updatePageNum: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.totalModel.fetch({
            success:function(model,response) {
                var total = response.data;
                var p = total/self.perPage;
                var r = total-Math.round(p) 
                self.maxPage = Math.ceil(p);  
                self.pagination = _.template($("#pagination_template").html(), {
                    pages:self.maxPage,
                    current:self.currentPage
                });

            }
        });
    },
```

Anyone that can help on this?

Comment: Just a thought, but try to wrap your numbers with `parseInt()`.

Comment: Your totally right on that one of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it has been solved in the comments, I'm posting it as an answer so it can be accepted.

You should wrap your numbers with `parseInt()`:

```
var total = parseInt(response.data, 10);
var p = parseInt(total/self.perPage, 10);
var r = parseInt(total-Math.round(p), 10);
```

Cheers.